# how to use beautiful soup to create a dictionary with headers and body

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a website ([example page](http://dailytruthbase.blogspot.com/2011/09/genesis-1-whats-first-thing-god-said.html)) and would like to use headers as keys and all the text underneath the header as the value. Here's what I'm doing thus far:

```
import requests
import bs4
urlMain = "http://dailytruthbase.blogspot.com/2011/09/genesis-1-whats-first-thing-god-said.html"
res = requests.get(urlMain)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
headers = soup.find_all('div',{'style':'text-align: center;'}) #This gets the 'header' (technically not a header, but it's what I need)
```

How do I get the text between the headers and pass it into a dictionary (e.g., `myDictionary = {"Psalm 1:1-3": "<the text from multiple paragraphs goes here>","<next header>","<text from more paragraphs>"}`)?

One thing I have tried is to find a function that returns all the text after a heading `find_all_next()`, but then it gets *everything* after the header and I want everything between the first and second heading.

Here's the code I used: `soup.find_all('div',{'style':'text-align: center;'})[2].find_all_next()` Maybe what I need is a "find_all_next_until"

For reference, here's what `headers` returns:

```
[<div style="text-align: center;">
 <b><b>Psalm 1:1-3 <u>Who Gets Blessed?</u></b></b></div>,
 <div style="text-align: center;">
 <span style="font-style: italic;"><br/></span></div>,
 <div style="text-align: center;">
 <b><b>Proverbs 1:7 <u>How Do We Become Wise?</u></b></b></div>,
 <div style="text-align: center;">
 <b>Genesis 1 <u>What's the First Thing God Said After He Created People?</u></b></div>,
 <div style="text-align: center;">
 <b>Genesis 1</b></div>,
 <div class="widget-content" style="text-align: center;">
 © 2015 William F. Cobb www.Truthbase.net; Graphics © 2015 Chesterton Cobb. Theme images by <a href="http://www.istockphoto.com/googleimages.php?id=10364914&amp;platform=blogger&amp;langregion=en" target="_blank">mammuth</a>. Powered by <a href="https://www.blogger.com" target="_blank">Blogger</a>.
 </div>]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you consulted the BeautifulSoup documentation? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I'm understand how to find individual elements or an entire group of elements, but how would I find all the elements that come after a specific element. For example, I could try: soup.find_all('div',{'style':'text-align: center;'})[1].next_siblings, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Also, I tried to edit to be more specific. For the record, though, I have been reading the docs and it doesn't seem like there's an obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.children` after a BeautifulSoup object to get the immediate descendants objects within, and not everything.  But I don't know how much that will help here.  There are several inconsistencies with this blog which make it difficult to really distinguish a "header" consistently.  There are some instances for example where "`<div style="text-align: center;">`" is not really the start of a new section.  Also, a look through the same page and some of the other pages on the blog reveals that unfortunately it's not always clear how a "header" is identified.

Going with your example though, it seems that the beginning of sections seem to follow this sort of format:

```
<div>  [This div tag contains everything for the whole section]

   ... some extra stuff ...

   <div class="foo" data-foo="3-1-4">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
         <b><b>Foo 3:1-4 <u>Yadda yadda</u></b></b>
      </div>
   <div>

   <div>
      ...start of content for this section
```

Every section is contained in one giant div, containing many little divs inside as direct children.  The first of these contains all the header info.  The remaining ones contain the section's content info.

So one approach is:

1. Look for any instances of the `div` tag with attribute `style="text-align: center;"` *and* containing an immediate `<b>` tag.  For the sake of clarity, let's call this the "header" div.
2. Go up two levels, to the `<div>` containing everything for the section.  Let's call this the "container" div.
3. From here, look at all of the divs within the container div, skip the first one (that's the header div), and take the text found in the rest.

Here's what I came up with when you do all of that and stick the results in a dictionary:

```
import requests
import bs4
urlMain = "http://dailytruthbase.blogspot.com/2011/09/genesis-1-whats-first-thing-god-said.html"
res = requests.get(urlMain)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

# Grab only the main content part of the page
main_blog = soup.find('div',{'class': 'new-post-style'})

# Identify every div tag that has style 'text-align: center;' AND contains a <b> tag.
all_text_center_divs = main_blog.find_all('div',{'style':'text-align: center;'})
headers = [h for h in all_text_center_divs if h.find('b')]

dict_info = {}
for h in headers:

    # Extract the header name
    header_name = h.b.find(text=True)

    # Go up two levels from the header div to get the div
    # containing the whole section.
    container_group = h.parent.parent

    # Take everything that's in the container group, in a
    # div tag, AFTER the first div (which has the header info)
    content = container_group.find_all('div', recursive=False)[1:]

    text_content = ''
    for c in content:
        stripped = c.text.strip()
        text_content += stripped + '\n'

    dict_info[header_name] = text_content

print(dict_info)
```

Comment: Question. I received "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'" on this page: http://dailytruthbase.blogspot.com/2011/09/genesis-32-34-friend-or-foe.html

I'm using a for loop and I assume the issue is that there is no tag on the page in question. How would I skip the page if the line "headers = [h for h in all_text_center_divs if h.find('b')]" errors?

Comment: That error seems to indicate that main_blog had a value of None. That implies "find('div',{'class': 'new-post-style'})" didn't return anything.  I do see that div tag in the code of the URL you just posted above, so I'm not sure what's wrong.  Does "soup" at least contain the code of the page, or is that None as well?